# Apache, SSL, LetsEncrypt, Ubuntu: Custom Domain with Sub Domains & SSL

Tags: server, 20.04, apache2, ssl, virtualhost

*Original Post at bottom*

How to setup Apache 2 with SSL certificates via Let's Encrypt on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS using a custom domain with sub domains (*a short guide by a guy who took too long to do something easy*)

**First caveat**

*If you break it you have to start over*

You can use Let's Encrypt's Apache plugin installer (which I recommend you do) via `sudo certbot --apache`. It does some automated `.conf` generation & installation into other `.conf` files read by Apache. If you start messing with certificates (deleting, moving) you will break it and I recommend deleting all certificates and starting over with **clean `.conf` files** ==>

**Second caveat**

If you are using virtual hosting, put them in separate files for each `VirtualHost` or else *certbot* will not install them correctly and will throw an error.

**STEP 1**: Create your `.conf` files for each `VirtualHost`.

1. Since I'm using `VirtualHost`s, I edited `000-default.conf` to start with `<VirtualHost _default_:80>` (this catches all resolving *.domain.com addresses which have not been declared by a `VirtualHost`). I also edited the `index.html` in the `DocumentRoot /var/www/html` to be a 'blank page' rather than the Apache Default Page.
2. Create a `.conf` for all your sub-domain `VirtualHost`s as below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webadmin@domain.com
    ServerName www.domain.com
    ServerAlias domain.com www.domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domain.error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        
</VirtualHost>
```

3. Starting with the first `.conf`, use `sudo a2ensite` to enable each `VirtualHost` `.conf`, then `sudo systemctl reload apache2` and confirm each of your `VirtualHost`s work correctly without interrupting the others.
4. Run `certbot --apache`, it will read your `sites-available\*.conf` and prompt you to select the sites for which you want to generate certificates.
5. (Optional) *Certbot* will prompt you to force redirect from HTTP to HTTPS. If you do, something like the following will be added into your `.conf` files:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.domain.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =domain.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
```

6. *Certbot* will automatically enable the newly generated SSL `.conf` files ending in `*-le-ssl.conf`.

Confirm that your sites work and you're done!

Please feel free to comment if you believe this can be updated in any way possible. I spent a week tinkering with settings only to find out that if you do it simple and clean it can be painless to start (at least for now!)

[Original Post for context]

```
Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, Apache 2, Let's Encrypt SSL certificates, Plex, Nextcloud, Website

**Questions:**
1. For `mydomain.com`, is it best practice to use a single `.conf` for `mydomain.com`, `subdomains.mydomain.com` and for both `:80` and `:443`?
2. I have certs via LetsEncrypt for @, www, plex, cloud (subdomains) - is this unnecessary?
3. What is best practice for setting up default vhost for :80 & :443? Should I only have a single `VirtualHost *.80`, and the rest are `subdomain.mydomain.com:80` ?
4. Once SSL works, what is the correct way to redirect http:// to https:// ? If a sub-domain does not support SSL, how can I exclude?

**Current status:** (I just broke everything, ignore below for now...)
- domain.com: :80 OK, :443 "This site can't provide a secure connection"
- www.domain.com: :80 OK, :443 "This site can't provide a secure connection"
- cloud.domain.com: :80 redirects to HTTPS, :443 "This site can't provide a secure connection"
- plex.domain.com: :80 redirects to mydomain.com:80, (no :443 yet)
- ssh.domain.com: :80 redirects to mydomain.com:80, (no :443 yet)
```

**My old single `.conf`:** https://pastebin.com/HWETrDfD

Comment: You can find the solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43470374/set-ssl-for-my-virtual-host/77502430#77502430, except for the "certificates via Let's Encrypt" part.